# Iot hub and rasberry pi

Tags: raspbian, wifi, windows-iot, usb-hub, wifi-direct

im makeing project but new in codeing , i want to connect cctv camera and ultra sonic sensor so if someone disobey the rule the camera will capture a photo and send it to online database and from the database it will be send to azure machine learning computer vesion which will take the car number plate number and search it in database and take his mobile number or any contact thing and send a report to the person who disobeyed the rule

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are asking for a tailored solution for your DiY project. Well I think the following links can point you to right direction as these are tutorials for interfacing RaspPi to Azure IoT hub service.

Its very detailed and will certainly provide the barebones of your project :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-node-get-started

(There is another version available using c)

Also there is a whole tutorial from Microsoft for the RaspPi 2 & 3 platform :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/

I would suggest you start along and post specific problems if and when you encounter them.